# Ext JS 4: JavaScript Exception "TypeError: Ext.resetElement is undefined" in Ext JS version 4.1.1

Tags: asp.net, proxy, extjs

Ext JS 4.1.1 broke my proxies I had set up with ASP.NET.  I had to switch back to version 4.1.0 to resolve the issue.  Just thought I'd throw this issue out there until it's resolved by Sencha.

**JavaScript Exception:**

"TypeError: Ext.resetElement is undefined" ==> "...s.styleProxyEl || (Ext.AbstractComponent.prototype.styleProxyEl" ==> ext-all-debug.js (line 26960)

[image]

```
getStyleProxy: function(cls) {

    var result = this.styleProxyEl || (Ext.AbstractComponent.prototype.styleProxyEl = Ext.resetElement.createChild({
        style: {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '-10000px'
        }
    }, null, true));

    result.className = cls;
    return result;
},
```

**Workaround:**

Download version 4.1.0 of the ExtJS framework instead of using version 4.1.1.

http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.0-gpl.zip

If someone can explain what broke here exactly, I'll mark their answer as correct.  Here is the proxy I'm using.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    require: 'Ext.data',

    buildRequest: function (operation) {
        var params = Ext.applyIf(operation.params || {}, this.extraParams || {}),
                                request;
        params = Ext.applyIf(params, this.getParams(params, operation));
        if (operation.id && !params.id) {
            params.id = operation.id;
        }

        params = Ext.JSON.encode(params);

        request = Ext.create('Ext.data.Request', {
            params: params,
            action: operation.action,
            records: operation.records,
            operation: operation,
            url: operation.url
        });
        request.url = this.buildUrl(request);
        operation.request = request;
        return request;
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you exactly mean with `broke my proxies I had set up with ASP.NET`

Comment: @sra - pasted my proxy class in the question

Comment: As far as I can tell the error is thrown while something is rendered by the Ext.util.Renderable mixin and I see nothing of that within your proxy. Have you had a look at the callstack?

Comment: I'm a newbie with JavaScript programming, but this ExtJS framework is beginning to grow on me.  Can you tell me where to find that?

Comment: You seem to use use firefox along with firebug. I am not quite shure if you can find a stacktrace there... I recommend you to use chrome with active developer tools. These will give you a stacktrace

Comment: In 4.1.1, Ext.resetElement is set to Ext.getBody() which is set to document.body.  This makes me wonder if your code is executing in script tags that are placed above the html body tag and not encapsulated in Ext.onReady()?  If this is the case make sure the code is executing within Ext.onReady().

Comment: I tried wrapping both the proxy code and my code with     Ext.onReady(function () { ..... code here ..... }); ... still didn't work :-\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another workaround that works for me is to define this element before using ext objects:

```
Ext.resetElement = Ext.getBody();
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are using `Ext.onReady(function() { ... })`. ExtJS uses `Ext.resetElement` which is set before `onReady` call.